# Search API for iTunes to retrieve app by giving app name not by lookup id

Tags: ios

I'm using this API https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=948595640 to get iTunes app/games based on lookup id and getting result correctly. The result with id=948595640 is the game **"Princess wedding pose"**. Now my scenario is to get the game **"Princess wedding pose"** by giving its name not by lookup id. I'm doing as https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Princess%20wedding%20pose but I'm not getting any result.
 Please give me any suggestions, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can include `entity=software` in the query, i.e. https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=princess+wedding+pose&entity=software

Because the default search include types (`movie`, `album`, `allArtist`, `podcast`, `musicVideo`, `mix`, `audiobook`, `tvSeason`, `allTrack`), which do not include `software`.

For full API reference, you can check in [this link](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/).

Comment: Is it possible to get limit more than 200, For Ex:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Glamour&entity=software&skip=0&limit=200
If the game with word "Glamour" had 400 games then what is the solution, I'm getting only 200 games any time